# Como buscar um determinado pacote pelo npm?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

Iniciei um projeto em React e quero saber como eu busco um determinado pacote instalado direto pelo npm ?

Comment: Para listar os pacotes instalado: `npm list -g --depth=0` e para listar um pacote em particular: `npm list -g --depth=0 | grep  nome-do-pacote`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra buscar um pacote, rode o seguinte comando:

```
npm search pacote_desejado
```

Por exemplo

```
npm search express
```

vai te trazer um resultado assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Valeu!

Answer (score -2):

Rode o comando abaixo no terminal:

```
npm list | grep {pacote_desejado}
```